# facebook login and youtube embed iframe clash

Tags: iframe, facebook, youtube, embed

so i have the two following iframe codes:

```
 <iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="some youtube url" allowfullscreen="" showinfo="0" frameborder="0" height="390" width="590"></iframe>
```

and

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=someid&xfbml=1"></script><fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

which when i check the source, the facebook code changes to

```
 <div class=" fb_reset" id="fb-root"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0pt; width: 0pt;"></div></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=someid&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:login-button class="  fb_iframe_widget " show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"><span><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login.php?api_key=somekey&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D0%23cb%3Dfe61c41eeb9262%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff231b08ff49befe%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dpostmessage&amp;locale=en_US&amp;max_rows=1&amp;sdk=joey&amp;session_key=2.erTTx_22d7lVclAChVw8dw__.3600.1300428000-517177672&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=200" class="fb_ltr" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 94px; width: 200px;" name="f216f1832512134" id="f3c59d11d032c" scrolling="no"></iframe></span></fb:login-button>
```

on the same page...

and for some reason, the iframe where the facebook login is supposed to appear ended up containing the youtube video so both iframes end up containing youtube video....

how would i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an old Firefox bug which it seems has finally been fixed in v4.0 beta:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=279048